# Shortes distance between two points on a cone

Tags: multivariable-calculus

We have a cone in the $3$-dim space whose base circle is on the $x$-$y$ plane and has a rotational symmetry by the z-axis. We need to calculate the shortest distance bewteen $(15,8,25)$ and $(20,-21,13)$ on the cone surface.

That's all the info I have. No function of the cone is given. Can someone help me with this? Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

**A start:** If you want the base radius and the height, note that the surface of the cone has equation of the shape $x^2+y^2=k^2(z-h)$. The parameters can be found from the fact that the two points are on the cone.