# Right circular cone shortest distance question from a junior high school st.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, 3d, geodesic

> Ant's shortest distance that it can travel
>   [image]

Can you show me the answer in the cone unfolded. I would be glad if you guys can show me the solution in a simple way because I am a high school student.

Comment: Literally, another ant.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/329731/721644) and [another one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2727463/705917).

Comment: Just look at all [those pictures](https://www.google.com/search?sa=X&sxsrf=ALeKk02jGFAOog3_v6cA6dDwdffnGBenjQ:1590710192902&source=univ&tbm=isch&q=%22shortest+distance%22+AND+%22cone%22+site:math.stackexchange.com&client=ms-android-samsung-ga-rev1&ved=2ahUKEwjHrPOf4dfpAhXlkIsKHT8YCH8QsAR6BAgKEAE&biw=1173&bih=2206).

Comment: Not to mention [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1897144/721644).

Answer (score 0):

Cut the cone along the segment $AT$. Unfolding, you get a sector of a circle. The apex $T$ of the cone becomes the center of the circle, and the point $A$ appears twice at opposite ends of the sector. The ant needs to go from one $A$ to the other $A$. Hints:

1. Determine the radius of the circle.
2. What fraction of the full circle does this sector represent? Hint: The base of the cone, when unwrapped, lives on the circumference of this circle.
3. Now you know the shape of the circular sector, in particular the central angle of the sector. The shortest distance from one $A$ to the other $A$ will be a straight line.

Comment: Yes, I know that it would be straight line but when you fold it the ant is actually goes to the top and goes down again. There is no surface area that the ant travels.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately the shape of the cone leads to a degenerate solution: the shortest distance has the ant going to the apex of the cone and then back down. Any other path that reaches the 'far' side of the cone travels a longer distance than this.